# ASP.NET MVC with MongoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Now I'm using C# MVC to implement an API, and the API data is from remote MongoDB. I found when I was testing my API, it had MongoDB connection timeout error appeared sometimes. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

This is the connection code

```
var settings = new MongoClientSettings
            {
                Credentials = new[] { MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential("database", "user", "pw") },
                Server = new MongoServerAddress("XXX.XXX.XXX", XXXXX),
                ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1800),
                MaxConnectionIdleTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1800),
            };

            //Get a Reference to the Client Object
            var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
            var mongoServer = mongoClient.GetServer();
            var database = mongoServer.GetDatabase("MongoDB");
```

Now I changed my code as follow, but I still encounter the same problem

```
var settings = new MongoClientSettings
            {
                Credentials = new[] { MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential("database", "user", "pw") },
                Server = new MongoServerAddress("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", XXXXX),
                ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1800),
                MaxConnectionIdleTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1800)
            };



            var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
            var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mongoDBdatabase"]);
            return database;
```

and get the data by the following code:

```
var database = Mongo.TestConnectDB();
            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("User");
            var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
            var filter = builder.Eq("_id", ObjectId.Parse(id));
            var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter);
            var friendList = new List<MongoModels.User.Circle.Friend>();

            while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                var user = cursor.Current;
                friendList=BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MongoModels.User>(user.First()).circle.friend;

            }
```

Comment: Show us your code so we can help.

Comment: Most likely it's incorrect connection string to DB. Check you connection string in Robomongo or in another tool.

Comment: Check, please, version of DB and c# driver.

Comment: MongoDB.Driver: 2.0.0.828 and MongoDB: 2.4.9

Comment: in driver 2.0 MongoServer is a deprecated class  http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/upgrading/?jmp=docs

Comment: I have tried using MongoClient to connect to the MongoDB server, but I still encounter the same problem

Comment: What's the error message that you are getting? Are you behind a firewall that would be limiting connectivity to the database? Does the database (not the mongo server) have the specified user credentials?

Comment: I got error code 10060, the message is "cannot get data from communication connection: the connection object haven't responded for a while or the connection builds fail". My lab server is using VM D2 edition on Microsoft Azure, so I'm not sure about it's settings. About credential of MongoDB, I found I can connect to it without user name and password, is that mean I didn't set credentials?